# Can i know the IP address of a Linux machine which is runing in virtual box if I'm not logged in?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ip-address

My question is: if I load a linux machine but I've not logged in with username and password, does this machine get an IP address? And if so, how to get this IP address? I have using Bridged mode and doing an nmap scan from my host windows7 machine is not showing this linux machine.

Comment: Try checking in your router DHCP log? It should show which IP address the virtual machine received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to checking the DHCP server logs or leases file, or even grabbing the MAC address of the VM from the config/settings page and setting a "static" address for it in your DHCP server, you could also edit the /etc/issue file and put the IP in there by doing it via script in /etc/rc.local or your distributions equivalent.

Comment: Thank you Ivanivan.. I have used nmap scan again, but this time I have selected the same network adapter for both my scanning machine and target network. (last time i had different network adapters selected). The target linux machine IP appeared in the nmap -sT scan. Also i have used hostonly network for both the machines. It worked.

Comment: awesome.  my experience is mostly from using a single template image that i keep cloning, so having it prepped with the script in rc.local to display the IP on the console screen, etc. is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The best free program to help you here is the utility "Wireless Network Watcher" by Nirsoft http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html

It scans your local network and brings up a table of IP addresses, device names, Mac Addresses and the Network adapter manufacturer.

Run this and immediately it will show you your network - Look for Virtualbox in the network adapter manufacturer and that will most likely be your virtual machine. The name of the computer as seen on the lan is also listed so check there as well - assuming you know the name of the machine.

Comment: Thanks Johnny. I have used nmap scan again, but this time I have selected the same network adapter for both my scanning machine and target network. The target linux machine IP appeared in the nmap -sT scan. Also i have used hostonly network for both the machines. It worked.